# (react & firebase ) Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to register a user with firebase but I have an error in the console that I can't solve.

First of all I tried to display an error message in case the password is less than 6 characters, it displays an error at the console level and does not display the error message at the user page level.

Secondly when I register with correct identifiers it adds the user in the firebase but there is still an error

```js
import React, { useState, useContext} from 'react'
import {FirebaseContext} from '../Firebase' 
const SignUp = () => {

  const firebase = useContext(FirebaseContext);

  const data = {
    pseudo: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    confirmPassword: ''
  }
  const [loginData, setLoginData] = useState(data);
  const [error, setError] = useState('')

  const handleChange = e => {
    setLoginData({...loginData, [e.target.id]: e.target.value})
  }
  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const {email, password} = loginData;
    firebase.signUpUser(email, password)
    .then(user =>{
      setLoginData({...data})
    })
    .catch(error => {
      setError(error);
      setLoginData({...data})
    })
  }
  const {pseudo, email, password, confirmPassword} = loginData;

  const btn = pseudo === '' || email === '' || password === '' || password !== confirmPassword ? <button disabled>Inscription</button> : <button>Inscription</button>
  const errorMsg = error !== '' && <span> {error.message} </span>
  return (
    <div className='signUpLoginBox'>
        <div className="slContainer">
            <div className='formBoxLeftSignup'>
            </div>
                <div className='formBoxRight'>
                    <div className='formContent'>
                        {errorMsg}
                        <h2>Inscription</h2>
                            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                                <div className='inputBox'>
                                    <input onChange={handleChange} value={pseudo} type="text" id='pseudo' required/>
                                    <label htmlFor="pseudo">Pseudo</label>
                                </div>

                                <div className='inputBox'>
                                    <input onChange={handleChange} value={email} type="email" id='email' required/>
                                    <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                                </div>

                                <div className='inputBox'>
                                    <input onChange={handleChange} value={password} type="password" id='password' required/>
                                    <label htmlFor="password">Mot de passe</label>
                                </div>

                                <div className='inputBox'>
                                    <input onChange={handleChange} value={confirmPassword} type="password" id='confirmPassword' required/>
                                    <label htmlFor="confirmPassword">Confirmez le mot de passe</label>
                                </div>
                                {btn}
                            </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
  )
}

export default SignUp
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

[error when the password does not reach the 6th character and the error message is not displayed on the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYB5z.png)

[error when registration is successful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WN0S0.png)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')
    at handleSubmit (SignUp.js:22:1)

Comment: It seems that `firebase.signUpUser` is undefined

Comment: If you `console.log(firebase)`, is it the value you're expecting? The error you're seeing here says that `firebase.signUpUser` is `undefined`, which means it doesn't have a property called `then`.

Comment: yes my console sends me an object with all the functions.

Comment: `class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    app.initializeApp(config);
    this.auth = app.auth()
  }

  signUpUser = (email, password) => {
    this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  }


  loginUser = (email, password) => {
    this.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  }


  signOutUser = () => this.auth.signOut()
}`